# How to write nested bash loop with condition

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to write a nested bash loop here. In every directory in my working directory, I have text files and I want to create a new directory called `nucleotide frequency' in each directory if I read the first text file. Here is what I tried, but it doesn't work.

```
for d in */ ; do
    echo "My Directories: " ${d}
    for f in $d/*.txt; do
        echo "My File: " ${f}
        if [f = 1]
        then
            mkdir $d/nucleotide_frequency
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Note that `mydir/myfile.txt` will never match `1`. If the file contains a single number you want to read, you can use `read value < "$f"; echo "The value was $value"`

Comment: @thatotherguy The duplicate you marked is completely different

Comment: I've reopened the question, but I don't understand how it's different. Is `bash: [f: command not found` or `dash: 5: [f: not found` not the error you're getting? Can you please edit the post and add the errors?

Comment: How about running your script through http://shellcheck.net/, fixing the problems it tells you about, and THEN asking for help with the parts that are still giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You were close. What was missing was your check for the text file.

This:

```
if [f = 1]
```

Is looking to see if the function or program `f` is equal to the number 1.

The bash built-in `if` function has a flag `-s` to check to see if file exists and has a size greater than zero.

```
for d in */
do
  echo "My Directories: ${d}"
  for f in "${d}"/*.txt
  do
    echo "My File: ${f}"
    # Let's make sure that the file exists and is not empty
    if [[ -s "${f}" ]]
    then
      mkdir "${d}"/nucleotide_frequency 2>/dev/null
      break
    fi
  done
done
```

---

[Introduction to if](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)

Comment: This is not working for me: `My Directories:  mitochondria/
My File:  mitochondria//*.txt
bash: [: missing `]'
My Directories:  retrotransposons/
My File:  retrotransposons//*.txt
bash: [: missing `]'
My Directories:  rRNA/
My File:  rRNA//*.txt
bash: [: missing `]'`

Comment: Jason, you'll need a space before the close-square-bracket on the `if` line, and it's generally recommended to use `[[` instead of `[` if POSIX portability isn't a factor. Also, it's a good idea to recommend that folks quote their variables and use `printf` instead of `echo` whenever possible. While it isn't always required, it's easier just to do it across the board than to understand where and how it's not an improvement. :) (And I'm looking forward to upvoting your first answer!)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I’ve edited the code to include a space after the square bracket. That thing gets me man.